# Exponential version of $CC^0$

Tags: reference-request, nondeterminism, polynomial-hierarchy

(In this question, "uniform" will mean $DLOGTIME$-uniform.)

In Allender's 1998 paper "The Permanent Requires Large Uniform Threshold Circuits", he talks about the "exponential versions" of uniform constant-depth circuit complexity classes. In particular:

- The exponential version of uniform $AC^0$ is the polynomial hierarchy $PH$, which is the closure of all languages $A \in P$ with the operations $NP^A$ and $coNP^A$.
- The exponential version of uniform $ACC^0$ is $ModPH$, which is the closure of languages $A \in P$ with operations $NP^A$, $coNP^A$, and $Mod_mP^A$, where the latter is defined as the set of languages $B$ such that there exists a nondeterministic Turing machine $M$ such that $x \in B$ if and only if $M^A$ accepts $x$ on a number of computational paths divisible by $m$.
- The exponential version of uniform $TC^0$ is the counting hierarchy, which is the union of $PP, PP^{PP}, PP^{PP^{PP}}, ...$

And by "exponential", it is meant that the larger classes listed above can be interpreted as alternating Turing machines with existential/universal, existential/universal/modular counting, and majority states respectively, making $O(1)$ alternations, and computing with polynomial time -- and if the time is reduced to logarithmic, the corresponding uniform constant-depth circuit classes are obtained instead.

What I couldn't find any mention of (in any paper) is what the exponential version of $CC^0$ is called -- that is, the closure of all languages $A \in P$ under $Mod_mP^A$. Is there a name for this class, or other papers about it? I'm especially curious about whether equality between this class and $ModPH$ is known, as an exponential analog of $CC^0$ vs $ACC^0$.

Comment: Languages in this class are called “$\oplus$-ptime predicates” in Buss, [Uniform proofs of ACC representations](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/uniformACC/), but I don’t think this is a particularly standard name. In any case, it is very close to ModPH: if you denote the class as $C$, then $\mathrm{ModPH=BP\cdot{}}C$.

Comment: Indeed, based on the intuition that one can glean from https://iuuk.mff.cuni.cz/~koucky/papers/acc.pdf it might be possible to show that the class you're asking about is actually equal to $ModPH$.  One way to attempt this would be to show that uniform $ACC^0$ can be solved by uniform (deterministic) quasipolynomial-size $CC^0$ circuits.  This would be interesting.  I think that it would probably require a few new ideas, though.